# Inheriting from Own class instead from XMLParserRuleContext

Tags: antlr4

I am using the 'visitor' pattern to generate XML from my parsed code. On typical context class looks like:

```
public static class On_dtmContext extends ParserRuleContext {
    public List<FieldContext> field() {
        return getRuleContexts(FieldContext.class);
    }
    public TerminalNode ON() { return getToken(SRC_REP_SCREENParser.ON, 0); }
    public On_dtm_headerContext on_dtm_header() {
        return getRuleContext(On_dtm_headerContext.class,0);
    }
.....
}
```

and I access the element in my visitors call back function using RuleContext's 'getText' member function.
I would like to write a class inheriting from 'ParserRuleContext' and overload 'getText' in order to replace characters like '<' or '>' with their xml escape sequences. Is there a way I can have my code generated and having the context classes inheriting from my class, as:

```
public static class On_dtmContext extends XMLParserRuleContext {
    public List<FieldContext> field() {
        return getRuleContexts(FieldContext.class);
    }
    public TerminalNode ON() { return getToken(SRC_REP_SCREENParser.ON, 0); }
    public On_dtm_headerContext on_dtm_header() {
        return getRuleContext(On_dtm_headerContext.class,0);
    }
.....
}
```

Thank you for your help!
Kind regards, wolf

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you are trying to extend the class, rather than creating a parser rule in your grammar to capture `<` and `>` so you can translate them as they occur?

The parser rules would look something like:

```
lessThan
    : '<'
    ;

greaterThan
    : '>'
    ;
```

At that point, you would have specific visitors for each of those terms and could translate them as you will.